# Paperclip upload causes update.js.erb to output code as text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been having this problem with Paperclip for a while.  New/Edit form submits and saves/updates, but create.js and update.js renders the code (that normally would be a view) as text to http://localhost:3000/albums/9.js (if it's the 9th album being updated), instead of a view in a modal on localhost:3000.

so instead of rendering a view, i get this text on /albums/9.js: $("#actionEdit").html("Album Updated.")

album model

```
belongs_to :band
  has_many :songs

  has_attached_file :album_artwork_1,
                    styles: { thumb: ["64x64#", :jpg] },
                    convert_options: { thumb: "-strip",
                                       original: "-strip" }

  has_attached_file :album_artwork_2,
                    styles: { thumb: ["64x64#", :jpg] },
                    convert_options: { thumb: "-strip",
                                       original: "-strip" }

  has_attached_file :album_artwork_3,
                    styles: { thumb: ["64x64#", :jpg] },
                    convert_options: { thumb: "-strip",
                                       original: "-strip" }

  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :album_artwork_1
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :album_artwork_2
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :album_artwork_3

  validates :album_name, presence: true
  validates :album_release_date, presence: true
```

albums controller

```
def new
    binding.pry
    @band = Band.find(params[:band])
    authorize @band, :admin?

    @album = Album.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @band = Band.find(params[:album][:band].to_i)
    authorize @band, :admin?

    @album = @band.albums.build(album_params)

    if @album.save

      @records = []
      @band.albums.each do |album|
        @records << album 
      end
      @band.eps.each do |ep|
        @records << ep 
      end
      @band.songs.each do |song|
        @records << song 
      end

      @records_ordered = @records #.sort.reverse!

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
    @band = Band.find(params[:band])
    authorize @band, :admin?

    @album = Album.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def update
    binding.pry 
    @band = Band.find(params[:album][:band])
    authorize @band, :admin?

    @album = Album.find(params[:id])

    if @album.update(album_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    else

      @fail = "w4rd"

      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

form

```
<%=simple_form_for(@album, remote: true, :authenticity_token => true, format: :js) do |f| %>

<% if @album.album_artwork_1.present? %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(@album.album_artwork_1.url(:thumb), class: 'media-object'), @album.album_artwork_1.url, target: '_blank' %> 
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :album_artwork_1, as: :file %>
    </div>

    <% if @album.album_artwork_2.present? %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(@album.album_artwork_2.url(:thumb), class: 'media-object'), @album.album_artwork_2.url, target: '_blank' %> 
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :album_artwork_2, as: :file %>
    </div>

    <% if @album.album_artwork_3.present? %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(@album.album_artwork_3.url(:thumb), class: 'media-object'), @album.album_artwork_3.url, target: '_blank' %> 
    <% end %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.input :album_artwork_3, as: :file %>
    </div>

<br><br>
    <div id="albumsubmit">
      <% if params[:action] === "edit" %>
        <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.button :submit, "Update Album", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% else %>
        <div class="form-actions">
          <%= f.button :submit, "Create Album", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>

   <% end %>
```

update.js.erb

```
$("#actionEdit").html("<%= j render 'updated' %>")
```

schema

```
create_table "albums", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.string "album_artwork_1_file_name"
    t.string "album_artwork_1_content_type"
    t.integer "album_artwork_1_file_size"
    t.datetime "album_artwork_1_updated_at"
    t.string "album_artwork_2_file_name"
    t.string "album_artwork_2_content_type"
    t.integer "album_artwork_2_file_size"
    t.datetime "album_artwork_2_updated_at"
    t.string "album_artwork_3_file_name"
    t.string "album_artwork_3_content_type"
    t.integer "album_artwork_3_file_size"
    t.datetime "album_artwork_3_updated_at"
```

params coming into #update

```
[1] pry(#<AlbumsController>)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"B/g/tnhObi6YmY6gqY0hTzJyiewshxVN6S1Dv+1yspGiRQZAlr8qdRiMtDyOh1/1VYvmr1FW9AsClLnW6xt9rg==", "album"=>{"band"=>"1", "album_name"=>"Test", "album_release_date"=>"2017-04-29", "produced_by"=>"", "recorded_at"=>"", "engineered_by"=>"", "second_engineers"=>"", "mixed_by"=>"", "mastered_by"=>"", "artwork_by"=>"", "photography_by"=>"", "art_direction_by"=>"", "construction_by"=>"", "booking"=>"", "litigation"=>"", "additional_musicians"=>"", "copyright"=>"", "websites"=>"", "contacts"=>"", "other"=>"", "album_artwork_2"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f681a3b4ca8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170416-32079-mie4xo.jpg>, @original_filename="c.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"album[album_artwork_2]\"; filename=\"c.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Update Album", "controller"=>"albums", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"7", "format"=>"js"} permitted: false>
[2] pry(#<AlbumsController>)>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can't upload via remote: true without the gem remotipart, which resolved the issue.